# how to pass id of a multiple dropdown inside the $.each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```js
function fieldsFilter(flag,value,chkClass)
 {
  var checkedfields = [];
  
  $.each($("#rep_id option:selected"), function(){            
            checkedfields.push($(this).val());
        });
  $('#'+flag+'Filters').val(checkedfields);
 }
```

Here i have a javascript function. Here i want to pass the chkClass in the place of rep_id in $.each(). i 
 am getting confusion.can one please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function fieldsFilter(flag,value,chkClass) {
    var checkedfields = [];
    $.each($(`#${rep_id} option:selected`), function(){
        checkedfields.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#'+flag+'Filters').val(checkedfields);
}
```